# Explicitly make a branch from origin/main's head

Tags: git

Is there a single git command for doing the following:

```
git switch main
git pull 
git branch XXX
git switch XXX
```

On one or two occasions I have created a branch while sitting in another branch, i.e. I forgot to do the first step above. I never make changes locally in my main.

You can call:

```
git branch XXX main
```

but that wont do the pull first. So as I understand it I have to switch to main anyway and do pull.

Comment: If you never make changes on the local `main`, I think you should wonder _why_ you have that branch locally in the first place.

Comment: @eftshift0 Only so that I can create a branch form it. Maybe I should be creating the branch in github and then pulling it locally.

Comment: Nope... you can create them locally by referencing the remote branch: `git branch new-branch origin/master` (or something like that with `git switch` or `git checkout `).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a *single* command built-in, but you can easily define one yourself combining two commands:

```
git fetch && git switch -c XXX origin/main
```

To define your own sub-command, use an alias:

```
git config --global alias.new '!f() { git fetch && git switch -c "$1" origin/main; }; f'
```

The function is required so that you can pass an argument (the branch name).

Alternatively,

```
git config --global alias.new '!f() { git fetch origin main:"$1" && git switch "$1"; }; f'
```

The latter will only fetch a single branch, while the former will update all remote-tracking branches.

Finally use the alias:

```
git new XXX
```